# VBScript filter function error

Tags: vbscript

I'm learning the array functions in VBScript and am a little confused on the  filter function, I created an array and  have then passed the filter function and its arguments to the msgbox function. but I keep getting 'error: type mismatch' on line 2 char 1.

```
colors = Array("blue","red")
msgbox filter(colors,"e")
```

the filter syntax is definetley correct because ive seen the exact same thing in the tutorial itself. Why do I get that error and how to fix it.
I intentionally don't want to use a FOR loop if possible (just to see if it's possible), I can get it working fine in a for loop and the join,split,ubound,a dlbound functions also work fine in or out of a for loop.

Comment: probably because `Filter` returns array, so maybe `MsgBox Join( Filter(colors,"e") )`

Comment: that works thanks, I thought filter automatically puts spaces in, or a user defined delimiter, as join and split does.